# Dependency Injection from Package Command

Tags: laravel, ioc-container, laravel-artisan

I am creating a command for my package.

My constructor is:

```
public function __construct(\Artisan $artisan)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->artisan = $artisan;
}
```

Protected `$artisan` property, of course, is present.

In my service provider `register()` method I have tried several methods for registering the command.

First:

```
$this->app['custom.command'] = $this->app->share(function ($app)
{
    return new CustomCommand(new \Artisan);
});
$this->commands('custom.command');
```

Second:

```
$this->app['custom.command'] = $this->app->share(function ($app)
{
    return $app->make('CustomCommand');
});
$this->commands('custom.command');
```

Normally, it is supposed to work. But when I run the command I always get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call()` error message as soon as I run `$this->artisan->call('migrate')` in my `fire()` method.

However when I write `\Artisan::call('migrate')` instead of the `$this->artisan->call('migrate')` everything works fine.

Does someone have an idea what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you inject the facade of Artisan and not Artisan itself.

Try

`public function __construct(Illuminate\Foundation\Artisan $artisan)`

and in your service provider:

`return new CustomCommand($app['artisan']);`

Comment: OMG, I thought about this several times but always rejected it as bad idea. Thank you very much! It works.